# Lebanon cadastral plot Deir Ez Zor/Levant Stereographic, EPSG:22780 conversion to KML projection issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, autocad, autocad-map

[image]

I am working Lebanon cadastral plot Deir Ez Zor/Levant Stereographic, EPSG:22780 coordinate reference system.  Once I convert to shapefile or KML there was 6 meter shift in Google Earth. Shift values vary from one region to another region.

Is there a way to fix the issue in ArcMap??

Comment: A shift comparing what? Please show exactly what is shifting.

Comment: Kml file shitting see the attached

Comment: I don't have data or ArcGIS to test, but maybe somewhere along the way that Deir_ez_Zor Datum with its TOWGS84[-190.421,8.532,238.69,0,0,0,0]] isn't being applied.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: The Shifting is very bad.
I have seen this so many times with Lebanese mapping, othophotos, Shapefiles and the likes, so many times. All over the place, not matching up. A Lebanese GIS users nightmare! We were opening and trying to georeference old Orthophotos of Lebanon, to see what the poor old Railroad and tramway network we used to have, looked like. We were trying to create a 3D Model of old lebanon with Photos my father had and re-create it in a Train Simulator. But the data was so off, it was unuseable.

Comment: Thanks Mr. @ Kriskol  strongly agree with you. i tried several method , projection , spatial adjustment noting help to be use the data